# How to make an point move up and down

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am trying to move a stick figure up and down in a `JFrame`. When I change the `y` it the whole thing moves. But I want it to move up, wait a second, then move down. `Thread.sleep` has not been working. `comp` is a object of a class draws the stick figure.

```
if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
{
    comp.setY(y++);
    comp.setY(y--);
}
```

Comment: if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
     comp.setY(y++);
     frame.invalidate();
     frame.validate();
     frame.repaint();
     try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     }
     comp.setY(y--);
    }

Comment: or this     if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
     comp.setY(y++);
     SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
     try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     }
     comp.setY(y--);
    }

Comment: Neither of these work. and sorry for so many comments, every time I tried to do a new line I accidentally commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing is a single threaded environment, it's also, reasonably optimised for what it does.

It's possible that the repaint manager is condensing the `repaint` requests down into a single request, so you only see the last request.

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

What you "can" do, is postpone the second update, using something like a Swing `Timer`...

Something like...

```
if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
{
    comp.setY(y++);
    // You may need to force a repaint here
    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            comp.setY(y--);
            // You may need to force a repaint here
        }
    });
    timer.setRepeats(false);
    timer.start();
}
```

...for example.

See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details.

Personally, I would setup a `Timer` which was capable of performing both the up and down movement based on a state variable it carries, but that's me

I would also discourage the use `KeyListener`s as they are just more trouble than they are worth, and instead would encourage the use of the Key Bindings API, see [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Comment: Sorry about that. Its quite a long class so i didnt put it on here